# Build version 1.2 or 1.2.0 for App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, versioning, semantic-versioning

I'm doing a new build and am increasing the build number. My guess would be that I should use `1.2.0` instead of `1.2` if we're looking at [Semver versioning](http://semver.org/). But, I don't know if Apple forces that and I would like if someone can link some official documentation (which I can't seem to find).

Comment: you search for apple document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While uploading new version or new build in same version make sure the pair of version number & build number must be unique.

**Case-1 : Adding new version**

- Make sure you need to increase version number
- Lets say if previous version number was 1.3 than next will be 1.4 or 2.0 or like that. It should not be less than 1.3
- Regarding build number for new version you can simply set 1.0.
- Later on if you required to upload new build for same version you just need to increase build number. While version no will be remain same.

**Case-2 : Adding new Build to same existing version**

- In the case if you required to upload new build for same version you just need to increase build number. While version no will be remain same.

**Important note :**

- Here is the Apples official documentation that explains more about the build no & version no : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2420/_index.html

Hope it will guide you.

Comment: Yeah, basically that guide you linked confirmed that I should probably use `1.2.0` as my build number.

Comment: Since this needs to be longer than 'Thanks'; Thanks! :)